# Update Counter in Angular factory with socket.io

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, counter

I'm trying to implement solution for automatically updating (increase) number of incoming data.

I'm listening for incoming messages and count them in factory:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('UpdateCounter', ['socketio', function (socketio) {
        var counter = { count: 0 };

        socketio.on('message', function (msg) {
            counter.count += 1;
            console.log(counter);
        });
        return counter;
}]);
```

I use this service in controller:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('CounterCtrl', ['$scope', 'UpdateCounter',  
        function($scope, UpdateCounter) {
            $scope.counter = UpdateCounter;
    }]);
```

to show increasing number of data:

```
<div class="text-center" ng-controller="CounterCtrl">
 <h3 count-to="{{counter}}" value="{{countFrom}}" duration="4" class="total-events"></h3>
</div>
```

In log I can see increasing number of messages [image], but I can't see increasing on the frontend (it's always 0)

I'm using [angular-count-to](http://sparkalow.github.io/angular-count-to/) to animate counting to a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing `$scope.countFrom` and it looks like `$scope.counter` is going to be an object.  Don't you need to pass a number into the `count-to` attribute?

**UPDATE**

Something else I just noticed: you're never including the count-to directive in your angular module declaration.  Try making it more like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['count-to']);
app.factory(.....);
app.controller(....);
```

Comment: I've added $scope.countFrom and nothing changed. Yes, I pass a number into count-to as you can see in example above:  count-to="{{counter}}"

Comment: "counter" is an object, not a number.  You might want to try passing it in as `{{counter.count}}`

Comment: One other thing I saw is that you're never including a reference to the count-to module in your app declaration...  Best practice is to define a variable for your app module and then define factories and controllers off f that.  See my edits above.

Comment: That's right, now it counts, but every time when message comes, it resets to 0 (it doesn't continue on the previous number) and then count to total number of messages :/ Thanks, I didn't mention, I've included 'count-to' directive in app.js

Comment: I put duration attribute to 0 and now counts well :) Thanks